# Why is 105th cyclotomic polynomial interesting?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial#Examples), the $105$th cyclotomic polynomial is interesting because $105$ is the lowest integer that is the product of three distinct odd prime numbers and this polynomial is the first cyclotomic polynomial that has a coefficient greater than 1.

$$
\begin{align}
\Phi_{105}(x) =\; &  x^{48} + x^{47} + x^{46} - x^{43} - x^{42} - 2 x^{41} - x^{40} - x^{39} + x^{36} + x^{35} + x^{34} \\
+ \;& x^{33} + x^{32} + x^{31} - x^{28} - x^{26} - \phantom{2}x^{24} - x^{22} - x^{20} + x^{17} + x^{16} + x^{15} \\
+ \;& x^{14} + x^{13} + x^{12} - x^{9\phantom{8}} - x^{8\phantom{8}} - 2 x^{7\phantom{8}} - x^{6\phantom{8}} - x^{5\phantom{8}} + x^{2\phantom{8}} + x^{\phantom{16}} + 1
\end{align}
$$

I don't see why this property of this particular polynomial makes it interesting, can anyone elaborate on this interesting coincidence?

Comment: After $104$ consecutive polynomials whose coefficients are all $-1$, $0$ or $1$, you should find it mildly refreshing to get something different. You might even have been starting to believe it would never happen.

Comment: @user208259 I'm mainly confused as to why the fact that 105 is the lowest integer that is the product of three distinct odd prime numbers, is interesting in related to this polynomial, sure it's the 105th such polynomial, but why is the prime factorization related.

Comment: It is relevant as one can show it cannot work for two prime powers or a power of two and two other prime powers. I expanded my answer in that sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say it is interesting or at least relevant to know that not all cyclotomic polynomials have coefficients in $\{-1,0,1\}$, which one might naively believe given a a list of the first few. To give the example $105$ is thus interesting and relevant; whether the exact phrasing is optimal to convey this is a matter of style.

To insist on the fact that $105$ is a product of three odd primes, is also pertinent. As it hints at the fact that numbers that are product of at most two prime powers have coefficients $\pm 1, 0$ only. And, also  for $n= 2^k p^n q^m$ this is still true. Yet it fails  for the first example that violates these conditions.

Continuing from there, there are various questions one can ask, for example one might try to characterize those $n$ for which one only has coefficients $\pm 1, 0$. For this problem see for example [Cyclotomic polynomials with coefficients $0,\pm 1$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109149/cyclotomic-polynomials-with-coefficients-0-pm1) on MO.

Comment: What is the first cyclotomic polynomial that has a coefficient bigger than 2 in absolute value?

Comment: I did not see that question until now sorry. You could try checking the cyclotomic polynomials for a few integers that are a product of three primes.

Comment: @Junglemath: 385. See http://oeis.org/A013594